# How different blocks of file processed in parallel on separate nodes?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Consider the below sample program for reference

```
val text = sc.textFile("file_from_local_system.txt");// or  file can also be on hdfs
val counts = text.flatMap(line => line.split(" ")
 ).map(word => (word,1)).reduceByKey(_+_) counts.collect
```

**My understanding :-**

1. Driver program creates the lineage graph(LG)/calculates the job ,stages and tasks.
2. Then ask the cluster manager(say spark standalone cluster manager) to allocate the resource based on tasks.

Hope it is correct ?

**Question:-**

My question is on step_1 . To calculate the number of task that can be executed parallely , driver program(DP) should 
also know the number of blocks stored on disk for that file.

Does DP knows it while constructing the LG and then tasks internally
contains the address of each block so that each can be executed parallely on separate node ?

Comment: Not happy with any of the answers?

Answer (score 1):

Quite interesting and not so trivial question !
After diving a bit more deeper in Spark's core source (2.4x), here's my understanding and answer proposal for your question:

1. General knowledge:

   - The main entry point for all Spark Actions is the SparkContext.
   - A Dag scheduler is instanciated from within SparkContext.
   - SparkContext has a runJob method, which itself informs the Dag scheduler to call its runJob method. It is called for a given RDD, and its corresponding partitions.
   - The Dag scheduler builds an execution graph based on stages which are submitted as TaskSets.
   - Hint: The Dag Scheduler can retrieve locations of blockIds by communicating with the BlockManagerMaster.
   - The Dag scheduler also makes use of a low-level TaskScheduler, which holds a mapping between task id and executor id.
   - Submitting tasks to TaskScheduler corresponds to builing TaskSets for a stage then calling a TaskSetManager.
   - Interesting to know: Dependencies of jobs are managed by the DAG scheduler, data locality is managed by the TaskScheduler.
   - Tasks are individual units of work, each sent to one machine (executor).
2. Let's have a look at Task.run()

   - It registers a task to the BlockManager:
     `SparkEnv.get.blockManager.registerTask(taskAttemptId)`
   - Then, it creates a TaskContextImpl() as context, and calls a runTask(context)
   - ResultTask class and ShuffleMapTask class both override this runTask()
   - We have one ResultTask per Partition
   - Finally, data is deserialized into rdd.
3. On the other hand, we have the family of Block Managers:

   - Each executor including the driver has a BlockManager.
   - BlockManagerMaster runs on the driver.
   - BlockManagerMasterEndpoint is and rpc endpoint accessible via BlockManagerMaster.
   - BlockManagerMaster is accessible via SparkEnv service.
   - When an Executor is asked to launchTask(), it creates a TaskRunner and adds it to an internal runningTasks set.
   - TaskRunner.run() calls task.run()
4. So, what happens when a task is run ?

   - a blockId is retrieved from taskId
   - results are saved to the BlockManager using:
     `env.blockManager.putBytes(blockId, <the_data_buffer_here>, <storage_level_here>, tellMaster=true)`
   - The method putBytes itself calls a: `doPut(blockId, level, classTag, tellMaster, keepReadLock)`, which itself decides to save to memory or to disk store, depending on the storage level.
   - It finally remove task id from runningTasks.
5. Now, back to your question:

   - when calling the developer api as: `sc.textFile(<my_file>)`, you could specify a 2nd parameter to set the number of partitions for your rdd (or rely on default parallelism).
   - For instance: `rdd = sc.textFile("file_from_local_system.txt", 10)`
   - Add some map/filter steps for example.
   - Spark context has its Dag structure. When calling an action - for example rdd.count() - some stages holding tasksets are submitted to executors.
   - TaskScheduler handles data locality of blocks.
   - If an executor running a task has the block data locally, it'll use it, otherwise get it for remote.
   - Each executor has its BlockManager. BlockManager is also a BlockDataManager which has an RDDBlockId attribute. The RDDBlockId is described by RDD ID (rddId) and a partition index (splitIndex). The RDDBlockId is created when an RDD is requested to get or compute an RDD partition (identified by splitIndex).

Hope this helps ! Please correct me if i'm wrong/approximate about any of these points.

Good luck !

**Links:**

- I've been reading Spark's core source: 
  https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/
  https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/storage/BlockManager.scala
- And reading/quoting: https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/spark-BlockManagerMaster.html

Answer (score 0):

This question is actually more complicated than one may suspect.

- This is my understanding for the case of HDFS which you allude to where the Data Node is the Worker Node. So, I exclude S3 and AZURE Blob Storage, 2nd Gen, etc. from this discussion, that is to say this explanation assume the Data Locality principle - which with Cloud Computing is becoming obsolete unless high performance is the go.
- The answer also excludes repartition and reducing aspects which also affects things as well as YARN Dynamic Resource Allocation, it assumes YARN as Cluster Manager therefore.

Here goes:

> Resource Allocation

- These are allocated up front by Driver requesting these from YARN, thus before DAG is created physically - which is based on Stages which contain Tasks. Think of parameters on spark-submit for example.
- Your 2nd point is not entirely correct, therefore.
- Depending on processing mode, let us assume YARN Cluster Mode, you will get a fat allocation of resources.

  - E.g. if you have a cluster of say, 5 Data / Worker Nodes, with 20 cpus (40 cores), then if you just submit and use defaults, you will likely get a Spark App (for N Actions) that has 5 x 1 core in total allocated, 1 for each Data / Worker Node.
- The resources acquired are held normally completely per Spark Job.
- A Spark Job is an Action that is part of a Spark App. A Spark App can have N Actions which are normally run sequentially.
- Note that a Job may still start if all resources are not able to be allocated.

> (Driver) Execution

- Assuming your file could have 11 partitions, 2 partitions for 4 Nodes and 1 Partition for the 5th Data / Worker Node, say.
- Then in Spark terms, a file as you specify using sc.textfile, is processed using Hadoop binaries which work on a Task basis per Block of the file, which means that the Driver will issues Tasks - 11 in total, for the first Stage. The first Stage is that before Shuffling required by reduce.

  - The Driver thus gets the information and issues a lot of Tasks per Stage that (are pipelined) and set for execution sequentially by that core = Executor for that Worker Node.
  - One can have more Executors per Worker / Data Node which would mean faster execution and thus throughput.
- What this shows is that we can be wasteful with resources. The default allocation of 1 core per Data / Worker Node can be wasteful for smaller files, or resulting skewed data after repartition. But that is for later consideration.

> Other Considerations

- One can limit the number of Executors per App and thus Job. If you select a low enough number, i.e. less than the number of Nodes in your Cluster and the file is distributed on all Nodes, then you would need to transfer data from a Worker / Data Node to another such Node. This is not a Shuffle, BTW.
- S3 is AWS Storage and the data is divorced from the Worker Node. That has to do with **Compute Elasticity**.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is on step_1 . To calculate the number of task that can be executed parallely , driver program(DP) should also know the number of blocks stored on disk for that file.
>
> Does DP knows it while constructing the LG and then tasks internally contains the address of each block so that each can be executed parallely on separate node ?

Yes, it's called "partitioning". There's a Hadoop Filesystem API call `getBlockLocations` which lists how a file is split up into blocks and the hostnames on which copies are stored. Each file format also declares whether a file format is "splittable"based on format (text, CSV, PArquet, ORC == yes) and whether the compression is also splittable (snappy yes, gzip no)

The Spark driver then divides work up by file, and by the number of splits it can make of each file, then schedules work on available worker processes "close" to where the data is.

For HDFS the block splitting/location is determined when files are written: they are written in blocks (configured) and spread across the cluster.

For object stores there is no real split or location; each client has some configuration option to control what block size it declares (e.g. fs.s3a.blocksize), and just says "localhost" for the location. Spark knows that when it sees localhost it means "anywhere"